# Extract all youtube video urls from homepage using python and selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, youtube

I'm looking to build a Youtube recommendations scraper which scrapes the Youtube homepage looking for youtube video ids/links for later download with youtube-dl. However, I do not know how/where to actually obtain this information.

My attempted code is below:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver/chromedriver')
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com")

while True:
    data = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("?")
    for i in data:
        l = i.get_attribute('href') #Should obtain some of the links/ids on the page but is None...
```

Comment: What exactly you trying to catch? I see that your first XPath `//*[(@class='watch_title')]` doesn't match any element

Comment: @Prophet, I realize I do not understand what I'm doing... I'm new to xpath... I would like to catch youtube links from the current page.

Comment: Well, he on SO you should ask very specific, clearly defined and focused questions, like this is what I tried so far, but I'm getting this error and I don't understand how to overcome this. Not "I want to do this and that, tell me how to do this" since such questions will be closed. These are rules here, it's not me :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your selection doesn't match any elements. By taking a simple look at the html-source of my youtube front-page i noticed, that every element that contains a video is an a-tag of the id 'thumbnail' which also has the direct attribute 'href':

[image: example]

given that, you can just find elements by this exact id and extract the given attribute "href" from it and filter it through a simple list comprehension like so:

```
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com")
hrefs = [video.get_attribute('href') for video in driver.find_elements_by_id("thumbnail")]

for href in hrefs:
    print(href)
```

OUTPUT:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PcYxbxXJhcc
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oTL52-NvyE4
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8kVI621fZug
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pr9TdbTDMH0
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iL9upp5jahg
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iWnb3IqCfgc
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ehAwNw4xDRM
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PzVj7s4JZhE
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7fBdqdqRxFM
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WMweEpGlu_U
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ljGwsbRLaI
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aUgEPebvR2Q
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gh6ovYtD2Q8
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dVICcSLIHCM
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bl6mPR5t6Dk
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mMKXCfTDjvg
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z_HhNWNm_jo
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZtiqfY8fixU
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9eAcRFlXxgo
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=omC2eg-d-6Q
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E90SOw7fIVk
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5qap5aO4i9A
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3ua3xTfbFI
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DTvS9lvRxZ8
```

always analyze the html-structure of your targeted source before scraping and then choose whats best for finding your data.

Comment: If you find elements by id, then any changes to the Youtube's source code will render it useless. Is there a more future-proof way to extract those elements?